# Is there a Unicode character that acts like a backspace or is invisible?

Tags: javascript, java, unicode, invisible, backspace

I was messing around with strings of random Unicode characters. I generated two different string that both had the same length. They were both populated with random Unicode characters between 0 and 255. I noticed after I ran the program the length of one string was different than the other. Dose anyone know if there is an invisible character or character that deletes there character before it in Unicode?

```js
//coded in javascript but the native language is Java
function generate(text) {
  //create an decode key array
  let decodeKey = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length * 2; i++) {
    decodeKey.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
  }
  let binary = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    //turn text to binary and split at every 4th character
    let b = text.charCodeAt(i).toString(2);
    while (b.length < 8) {
      b = "0" + b;
    }
    binary.push(b.slice(0, 4));
    binary.push(b.slice(3));
  }
  //convert binary to a number and multiply by the decode key
  let nums = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
    nums.push(parseInt(binary[i].toString(10)) * decodeKey[i]);
  }
  //convert nums to unicode
  let uniChars = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    uniChars.push(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(nums[i])));
  }
  //create final string with decode key at the bottom
  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < uniChars.length; i++) {
    result += uniChars[i];
  }
  result += "\n"
  for (let i = 0; i < decodeKey.length; i++) {
    result += String.fromCharCode(decodeKey[i]);
  }
  //return the result
  return result;
}

console.log(generate("Test / Sample Text, Test / Sample Text, Test / Sample Text, Test / Sample Text"));
```

Comment: In which programming language? Different languages have different definitions of what the "length" of a string is.

Comment: Java I was writing to a file and when I reread the file the 2 string didn't match up

Comment: Depending on what OS and language you're using, there may be a dedicated "end of file" character, or a dedicated "end of string" character (often NUL), either of which would terminate things prematurely.

Comment: Reread the file using the same language?

Comment: I reread the file using the same language, Java.

Comment: Posting the actual code you used to both write and read the file would probably help. One thing that's almost certainly not relevant here is Unicode itself.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], and also the bytes of the file that is generated.

Comment: There is certainly a Unicode character that acts like a backspace. Backspace. But writing it into a file isn't going to delete one of the characters in the file.

Comment: The exact Java code is relevant here.  Converting bytes to characters always requires a [Charset](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html), even if it’s an implicit one, and that Charset may not treat each byte as a single character.

Comment: Javascript or Java? What you've written is Javascript, so I'm not sure why you've tagged Java

Comment: Beware of `char` type in Java. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters.  For example, `"".length()` fails, [returning 2](https://ideone.com/gtvVyl) rather than 1. Use code point integers instead.

Comment: Why are you showing JavaScript if your problematic code is in Java?? This Question needs a clear and simple [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Because I cant insert a working java applet into stackoverflow so instead I added a javascript version of what my java program is doing

Comment: We don’t need to see a working applet.  We need to see the *code* for your applet.  You can safely assume that we know how to compile and run programs.